# Issue with a JSON Query

Tags: php, ajax, json

I Use a json onclick script for triggering a php function.
I call the php function with:

```
$('#dtable').on('click', '[name=option3]', function () {
    var select = $(this);
    var id = select.attr('id');
    $.post('index.php/stop/'+id+'', function(json) {
            if (json && json.status) {
                $("#failure").show().delay(2500).fadeOut(1500);
            } else {
                $("#success").show().delay(2500).fadeOut(1500);
            }
        }
    );
} );
```

If the item is trigger he calls a slim property in my index.php

```
$admin->slim->post('/stop/:action', function($action) use ($admin) {
    $admin->slim->contentType('application/json');
    echo json_encode($admin->cont->Stop($action));
```

After this he triggert the function

```
function Stop($action) {
    $port = $action;
    $connection = @fsockopen($this->cfg->base_host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
    if (!$connection) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $pid = $this->db->query("SELECT pid FROM testdb WHERE port='" . $port . "'", SQL_ALL, SQL_ASSOC);
        if ($pid == "") {
            return false;
        } else {
                  ......
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the only thing is that the answer from json is always success
but there is no return from true or false from the function

Does someone knows what i doing wrong or can someone give me some advice.

- Added more information about the function

Comment: you have to wrap your response in `json` and then echo it i didn't see any echo

Comment: When i do the query with slim 
i use     echo json_encode($admin->cont->Stop($action));

Comment: *"only thing is that the answer from json is always success but there is no return from true or false from the function"* What do you mean by that? Do you mean that what you get back in the callback function at `$.post('index.php/stop/'+id+'', function(json) {` doesn't contain any json? Or does that function not work as you intend it to work?

Comment: What i try to do is make a call to trigger the function. the ID in the call is a port number and this changes a couple of times within the page. 

If the function is done then i want to show a success message if the function is failed then i want to show a failed message.

In the function i have put in a couple off return false and a return true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `alert(json);` before `if (json && json.status)` to see what you get. I'm sure `json` is not what you expect. It seems `json == false` (because function `Stop()` return `false`) and there is no `json.status` - or maybe rest of your `Stop` function return something more.

Comment: i have put in the alert(json); i get indeed the message false

how do you mean there is no json.status?

Comment: Sorry i have seen that there is no status like you said.
If i change the code to return true json alert says true and the message show the same message when it is false.

Comment: I have placed the alert(json.status); on the same page and i get as a message undefined. On this moment i don't know where i must find the issue

Comment: I think you expect too much. `json` includes only datas send by `echo json_encode(...);` and nothing more (and therefore in all examples it is named 'data', not 'json'). if you expect json connection status in `json.status` you are wrong.

Comment: Now you can use only `if(json) {...} else {...}`

Comment: btw: see [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) in jQuery docs. if you need message with json connection status use `$.post(... , function(json,textStatus){ alert(textStatus); ... }`

Comment: may i thank you for your advice.
I have removed the json.status and the script is working on this moment. I go look @ the jquery docs for the post function.
For now i can test the script